# Compare data in 5th column with 6th column and print the least difference element

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with below data:

```
APPLE,FRUIT,1KG,RED,1660.00|1680.00|1700.00|1720.00|1740.00|1760.00|1800.00|1900.00|1920.00|1520.00|1320.00|1340.00|1360.00|1380.00|1400.00|1420.00|1440.00|1460.00|1480.00|1940.00|940.00|1880.00|1820.00|1840.00|1860.00|1780.00|1500.00|1020.00|1040.00|1060.00|1080.00|1100.00|1120.00|1140.00|1160.00|1180.00|1200.00|1220.00|1240.00|1260.00|1280.00|1300.00|960.00|980.00|1000.00|1540.00|1560.00|1580.00|1600.00|1620.00|1640.00,1429.100000
ORANGE,FRUIT,2KG,GREEN,1660.00|1680.00|1700.00|1720.00|1740.00|1760.00|1900.00|1920.00|1500.00|1320.00|1340.00|1360.00|1380.00|1400.00|1420.00|1440.00|1460.00|1940.00|1800.00|940.00|1880.00|1820.00|1840.00|1860.00|1780.00|1480.00|1020.00|1040.00|1060.00|1080.00|1100.00|1120.00|1140.00|1160.00|1180.00|1200.00|1220.00|1240.00|1260.00|1280.00|1300.00|960.00|980.00|1000.00|1520.00|1540.00|1560.00|1580.00|1600.00|1620.00|1640.00,1432.100000
```

I want to check each value in column 5(delimiter to get column 5 is ","). Compare the same with column 6 and get the least difference element into the new file.

Expected output is:

```
APPLE,FRUIT,1KG,RED,1420.00
ORANGE,FRUIT,2KG,GREEN,1440.00
```

My file has more than 200 rows, looking for a one liner command to do the same.

Comment: Your name is 'programmer'... well what have you 'programmed' on your own so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I need a one liner to do the same. What I know is writing the same in a shell script using while loop. I will loop through each line and find the difference. The least difference I will consider. I was looking for one liner to achieve the same.

Comment: I cooked up a oneline solution, but it's in python and the tags state `bash`.

Comment: I am looking for a command in linux. As the file which I am referring to is in linux. I have been working around with php and shell script. So not sure how to fit in python. Can you share the solution, so that I will try to fit in the same, if possible.

Comment: @Panki please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: I have added the tag awk. I was looking for awk command one liner itself.

Comment: @Panki if it's a one-liner, then sure, you may as well.

Comment: This is not a one  liner right? I need to run my file in the loop right?

Comment: Yes it needs to process the file line by line. I don't really know what other solution there would be.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the same. Will check if someone can help me with awk itself.

Comment: Do you want the closest value irrespective of whether it is less or more? If the last column is 100 and you have both 99 and 101 in the 5th column, which value should be chosen?

Comment: Any value is fine. I just needed the closest one. In this case of 100, 99 and 101, you can give me an option to select +ve difference or -ve difference? Only if possible, else 99 or 101, any random number is fine among the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my Python solution.

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x=line.split(',')
        y=x[4].split('|')
        print(','.join(x[:4]) + ',' + str(min(y, key=lambda z: abs(float(z)-float(x[5])))))
```

If you have something like Pyed Piper, also known as `pyp`, you can run this straight from the terminal prompt: https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyp/

Comment: Thanks for the share. I am able to get the desired result with this.

Answer (score 2):

As an AWK solution is requested, I will give one.

```
awk -F, 'NF>4{
        n=split($5,a,"|")
        l=a[0];
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
                if((a[i]-$6)^2<(l-$6)^2)
                        l=a[i];
        print $1","$2","$3","$4","l                                                                                                                                                                                
}' input > output
```

Comment: +1, clever use of `^2` to get around the absence of an `abs` function in `awk`